# Difference between devices coordinate systems and libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport, galaxy, coordinate

I have a problem with libgdx and coordinate systems of devices. 
With galaxy S I Have a coordinate system with the (0,0) coordinate in the left high corner and the y-axis crescent downside. i.e. My sample:

```
x=0,y=device height
_________________________x=device width

    |
    |
    |
    |

x=0,y=0
```

And my app work fine finally in galaxy S4 I have the next sistuation:

```
x0=y=0
______________________________________
|
|
|
|
x=0,y=device height
```

As result of this the image is rotated of 180 degree. 
Please, how I can build a coordinate system indipendent from the device?
Thanks for your Attention.

Edit:
in the splash screen I set this code in the constructor

```
 camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Constants.APP_WIDTH, Constants.APP_HEIGHT);
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sfondosplashscreen.png"));
        viewport = new FitViewport(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
```

and the follow code in the resize method

```
 @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
```

this work in both devices.

In the main menu I use the same code. in galaxy s work and in galaxy s4 don't work.....

Comment: show the code on how you manage your [viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

Comment: Your `Viewport` in the example here does not get any `camera`. Therefore it creates it's own camera. The 3rd param of the constructor should be your `camera`.

Comment: update code with viewport = new FitViewport(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(),camera); still work in galaxy s and still don't work in galaxy s4   :(

Comment: Are you using the same `camera` to render the things? Did you call `camera.update()` before rendering?

Comment: I have discoverd the reason. I calculated the position of same element with a formula. well that formula was wrong.  sometimes the result was negative and hence the image was reflected.....